# ARM 32 bit STR instruction

Tags: assembly, arm

I have not much experience in programming ARM, I'm trying to launch follow programs:

```
_start:
        STMFD SP!, {R11,LR}
        ADD   R11, SP, #4
        SUB   SP, SP, #0x18
        SUB   R12, R11, #24
        mov r5, #74 ;index for loop
        ldr r3, =data
        mov lr, r3
        LDMIA LR!, {R0-R3}
        STMIA R12!, {R0-R3}

_loop:
        str r12,[lr],#4
        subs r5,r5,#1
        bne _loop
```

But I have a SIGSEGV after this instruction:

```
str r12,[lr],#4
```

this is a dump of the memory:

```
(gdb) x/10x $r12
0xbeb6c944: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000001
0xbeb6c954: 0xbeb6ca79  0x00000000  0xbeb6ca8b  0xbeb6caa3
0xbeb6c964: 0xbeb6cab6  0xbeb6cabd
```

I think the problem is due to the fact that the stack is not writable, but why in this instruction STMIA R12!, {R0-R3} I don't have any problem?

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: What value does the symbol `data` have?

Comment: data: .asciz "/system/bin/curl"
http: .asciz "http://website/file.txt"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the ARM docs for `str`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/BABFGBDD.html), `str r12,[lr],#4` stores r12 into the address in `lr`, with post-index (`lr+=4` after the store).  The square brackets indicate the dereference / memory operand, like in x86 syntax.

Since you showed the output for `x/10x $r12`, I think you're mixed up on which register is the data and which is the address.